# Check Capslock In Pygame.Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, key, capslock

I wrote a notetaking app, which provides with easier usage, but I cannot check whether the caps lock button is on or off. I can get the value when it is turned on, but there is not any response when it is turned off. In other words, I can get the output of the key when the led is turned on, but not when it is turned off.

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import subprocess
from pygame.locals import *
time_a = time.time()
slides = []
POS = (0,0)
capslock = False
altcizgi = False
italic = False
bold = False
yazi = ""
character = ""
time_d = 0
sayim = 0
time_b = 0
buyukluk = 30
liste = []
r = ""
rty = ""
time_c = 0
durum = 0
sol_bas = -100
WHITE= (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GREY = (200,200,200)
ORANGE = (200, 100, 50)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
MAGENTA = (255, 0, 255)
TRANS = (1, 1, 1)
firca_ucu = 3
# initializations
pygame.init()
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w, infoObject.current_h))
pygame.display.set_caption('Noting')
pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w, infoObject.current_h), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
color = (0, 0, 0)
startPos = (0, 0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background.fill((255, 255, 255))
image = pygame.image.save(background,'image.png')
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 150)
colorName = "Black"
welcomeFont = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)
colorConfigFont = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 35)
welcomeScreen = True
# mainloop
while 1:
    # welcomescreen
    while welcomeScreen:
        for i in pygame.event.get():
            mainScreenPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            screen.fill((0,0,0))
            screen.blit(welcomeFont.render("Paint Program Keys", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 50))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Left: Decrease Punto", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 150))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Right: Increase Punto", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 200))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Up: Increase Brush Size", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 250))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Down: Decrease Brush Size", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 300))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Space: Draw On/Off", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 350))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Backspace: Backspace", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 400))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Control: Italic", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 450))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F7: ", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 500))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Mouse-Click: Text", True, (0, 255, 0)), (900, 550))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("ESC: Main Menu", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 150))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F1: Draw Square", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 200))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F2: Draw Circle", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 250))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F3: Draw Triangle", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 300))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F4: Import", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 350))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F5: Save", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 400))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F6: Clear", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 450))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F7: Previous Song", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 500))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F8: Stop/Play Song", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 550))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F9: Next Song", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 150))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F10: Mute", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 200))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F11: Decrease Volume", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 250))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("F12: Increase Volume", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 300))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Tab: Undo", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 350))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Alt: Underline", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 400))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Enter: Caps-Lock", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 450))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("Shift: Draw On/Off", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 500))
            screen.blit(colorConfigFont.render("CMD: Bold", True, (0, 255, 0)), (500, 550))
            screen.blit(welcomeFont.render("Press 'ESC' to continue", True, (0, 255, 0)), (100, 700))
            pygame.display.flip()
            if mainScreenPressed[K_ESCAPE]:
                durum = -1
                welcomeScreen = False
                time_d = time.time()


            class Slider():
                def __init__(self, name, val, maxi, mini, pos):
                    self.val = val  # start value
                    self.maxi = maxi  # maximum at slider position right
                    self.mini = mini  # minimum at slider position left
                    self.xpos = 1300  # x-location on screen
                    self.ypos = pos
                    self.surf = pygame.surface.Surface((100, 50))
                    self.hit = False  # the hit attribute indicates slider movement due to mouse interaction

                    self.txt_surf = font.render(name, 1, BLACK)
                    self.txt_rect = self.txt_surf.get_rect(center=(50, 15))

                    # Static graphics - slider background #
                    self.surf.fill((100, 100, 100))
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.surf, GREY, [0, 0, 100, 50], 3)
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.surf, ORANGE, [10, 10, 80, 10], 0)
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.surf, WHITE, [10, 30, 80, 5], 0)

                    self.surf.blit(self.txt_surf, self.txt_rect)  # this surface never changes

                    # dynamic graphics - button surface #
                    self.button_surf = pygame.surface.Surface((20, 20))
                    self.button_surf.fill(TRANS)
                    self.button_surf.set_colorkey(TRANS)
                    pygame.draw.circle(self.button_surf, BLACK, (10, 10), 6, 0)
                    pygame.draw.circle(self.button_surf, ORANGE, (10, 10), 4, 0)

                def draw(self):
                    """ Combination of static and dynamic graphics in a copy of
                the basic slide surface
                """
                    # static
                    surf = self.surf.copy()

                    # dynamic
                    pos = (10 + int((self.val - self.mini) / (self.maxi - self.mini) * 80), 33)
                    self.button_rect = self.button_surf.get_rect(center=pos)
                    surf.blit(self.button_surf, self.button_rect)
                    self.button_rect.move_ip(self.xpos, self.ypos)  # move of button box to correct screen position

                    # screen
                    screen.blit(surf, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

                def move(self):
                    """
                The dynamic part; reacts to movement of the slider button.
                """
                    self.val = (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - self.xpos - 10) / 80 * (self.maxi - self.mini) + self.mini
                    if self.val < self.mini:
                        self.val = self.mini
                    if self.val > self.maxi:
                        self.val = self.maxi

    # paint screen
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[K_RMETA] or pressed[K_LMETA] and pressed[K_q]:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        rn = time.strftime("%H.%M %d:%m:%Y")
        pygame.image.save(background, "/Users/Esat/Desktop/Noting/Saved_Work_at_"+rn+".jpg")
        exit()
    if pressed[K_F1]:
        pass
    if pressed[K_F2]:
        pass
    if pressed[K_ESCAPE]:
        if time.time()-time_d>0.5:
            welcomeScreen = True
    if pressed[K_F4]:
        input_screen = True
        background = pygame.image.load("/Users/Esat/Desktop/Noting/Imports/"+data+".jpg")
    if pressed[K_F5]:
        if time.time()-time_c>5:
            rn = time.strftime("%H.%M %d:%m:%Y")
            pygame.image.save(background, "/Users/Esat/Desktop/Noting/"+rn+".jpg")
            background.fill(WHITE)
            screen.fill(WHITE)
            time_c = time.time()
        else:
            pass
    if pressed[K_F6]:
        background.blit(font.render(yazi, True, (color)), (POS))
        pygame.image.save(background, 'image.png')
        liste = []
        yazi = ""
        r = ""
        background.fill((255,255,255))
    if pressed[K_F7]:
        pass
    if pressed[K_F8]:
        pass
    if pressed[K_F9]:
        pass
    if pressed[K_F10]:
        pass
    if pressed[K_F11]:
        pass
    if pressed[K_F12]:
        pass
    if pressed[K_LMETA] or pressed[K_RMETA]:
        bold = True
    if pressed[K_LALT] or pressed[K_RALT]:
        altcizgi = True
    if pressed[K_LCTRL] or pressed[K_RCTRL]:
        italic = True
    if pressed[K_UP]:
        if rty == "eraser":
            firca_ucu = firca_ucu * 1.04
        elif rty != "eraser":
            firca_ucu = firca_ucu*1.02
    if pressed[K_DOWN]:
        firca_ucu = firca_ucu*0.98
    if pressed[K_RIGHT]:
        buyukluk = buyukluk*1.02
    if pressed[K_LEFT]:
        buyukluk = buyukluk*0.98
    if buyukluk<1:
        buyukluk =1
    if buyukluk>300:
        buyukluk =300
    if firca_ucu<1:
        firca_ucu =1
    if rty != "eraser":
        if firca_ucu>30:
            firca_ucu =30
    if rty == "eraser":
        if firca_ucu>250:
            firca_ucu =250
    #if pressed[K_CAPSLOCK]:
     #   print(time.time()-time_b)
      #  if time.time()-time_b>0.3 and time.time()-time_b<9999999:
       #     if capslock == "off":
        #        capslock = "on"
         #   elif capslock == "on":
          #      capslock = "off"
        #time_b = time.time()

 `      if pressed[K_TAB]:
            background = pygame.image.load('image.png')



    if pressed[K_SPACE]:
        if time.time() - time_a > 0.2:
            durum = durum+1
            if durum == 1:
                pygame.image.save(background, 'image.png')
            if durum >1:
                durum = 0
            time_a = time.time()

    #pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        endPos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        end_x,end_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if i.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            background.blit(font.render(yazi, True, (color)), (POS))
            liste = []
            yazi = ""
            r = ""
            italic = False
            bold = False
            altcizgi = False
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


        elif i.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            for s in slides:
                s.hit = False

        if r=="rend":
            if i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                character = pygame.key.name(i.key)
                character = character.lower()
                print(character)
                if character == "space":
                    background.blit(font.render(yazi, True, (color)), (POS))
                    liste = []
                    yazi = ""
                    r = ""
                    character = ""
                if character == "return":
                    character = " "
                elif character == "world 0":
                    character = "ü"
                elif character == "world 1":
                    character = "ğ"
                elif character == "world 2":
                    character = "ı"
                elif character == "world 3":
                    character = "ş"
                elif character == "world 4":
                    character = "ö"
                elif character == "world 5":
                    character = "ç"
                print(capslock)
                if capslock == True:
                    character = character.upper()
                if capslock == False:
                    character = character.lower()
                if character == "backspace" or character == "BACKSPACE":
                    liste = liste[:-1]
                    yazi = ''.join(liste)
                else:
                    if len(character) < 2:
                        liste.append(character)
                        yazi = ''.join(liste)

        if i.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            endPos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0):
            POS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if y>848:
                if x<100:
                    color = (130, 0, 0)
                elif 100<x<200:
                    color = (255, 0, 0)
                elif 200<x<300:
                    color = (255, 193, 0)
                elif 300<x<400:
                    color = (249, 255, 0)
                elif 400<x<500:
                    color = (121, 218, 76)
                elif 500<x<600:
                    color = (0, 187, 81)
                elif 600<x<700:
                    color = (0, 176, 244)
                elif 700<x<800:
                    color = (9, 21, 98)
                elif 800<x<900:
                    color = (125, 0, 161)
                elif 900<x<1000:
                    color = (122, 122, 0)
                elif 1000<x<1100:
                    color = (122, 0, 122)
                elif 1100<x<1200:
                    color = (0, 122, 122)
                elif 1200<x<1250:
                    color = (0, 0, 0)
                elif 1250<x<1300:
                    color = (255,255,255)
                elif 1300<x<1400:
                    sayim = sayim+1
                    if sayim == 1:
                        font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 20)
                        pen = Slider("Red", 10, 255, 1, 700)
                        freq = Slider("Green", 1, 255, 1, 750)
                        jmp = Slider("Blue", 10, 255, 1, 800)
                        slides = [pen, freq, jmp]
                        font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', round(buyukluk))
                    if sayim >1:
                        sayim = 0
                        color = (pen.val,freq.val,jmp.val)
                        slides = []
            else:
                r = "rend"
                durum  =0
        if durum == 1:
            #pygame.draw.rect(background, color, (end_x,end_y,round(firca_ucu),round(firca_ucu)))
            pygame.draw.line(background, color, startPos, endPos, round(firca_ucu))

        if durum >1:
            durum = 0
        startPos = endPos
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (sol_bas + 100, 850, 100, 50))
    if durum == 1:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 25)
        screen.blit(font.render("Size: "+str(round(int(firca_ucu)))+"", True, (0, 0, 0)), (5, 883))
        if color == (255,255,255):
            rty = "eraser"
            screen.blit(font.render("Eraser", True, (0, 0, 0)), (30, 853))

        else:
            rty = ""
            screen.blit(font.render("Pen", True, (0,0,0)), (5, 853))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color), (sol_bas+150, 850, 50, 25))
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', round(buyukluk))
    else:
        rty = ""
        if r == "rend":
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 25)
            screen.blit(font.render("Text", True, (0, 0, 0)), (5, 853))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color), (sol_bas + 150, 850, 50, 25))
            screen.blit(font.render("Size: " + str(round(int(buyukluk))) + "", True, (0, 0, 0)), (5, 883))
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', round(buyukluk))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (sol_bas + 100, 873, 100, 4))
    if rty != "eraser":
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (sol_bas + 148, 850, 4, 25))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (sol_bas + 100, 873, 100, 4))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (sol_bas + 100, 873, 100, 4))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (sol_bas + 195, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (sol_bas+200, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 193, 0), (sol_bas+300, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (249, 255, 0), (sol_bas+400, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (121, 218, 76), (sol_bas+500, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 187, 81), (sol_bas+600, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 176, 244), (sol_bas+700, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (9, 21, 98), (sol_bas+800, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (125, 0, 161), (sol_bas+900, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (122, 122, 0), (sol_bas+1000, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (122, 0, 122), (sol_bas+1100, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 122, 122), (sol_bas+1200, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (sol_bas + 1300, 850, 50, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (sol_bas + 1350, 850, 50, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (1300, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 122, 0), (1310, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (1320, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (1330, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 255), (1340, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 122, 255), (1350, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (1360, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (122, 0, 255), (1370, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 255), (1380, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 122), (1390, 850, 10, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, 848, 1400, 4))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 100)
    screen.blit(font.render("+", True, (0, 0, 0)), (1330, 840))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', round(buyukluk))
    if r == "rend":
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', round(buyukluk))
        if altcizgi == True:
            font.set_underline(True)
        elif altcizgi == False:
            font.set_underline(False)
        if bold == True:
            font.set_bold(True)
        elif bold == False:
            font.set_bold(False)
        if italic == True:
            font.set_italic(True)
        elif italic == False:
            font.set_italic(False)
        screen.blit(font.render(yazi, True, (color)), (POS))

    if slides !=[]:

        for s in slides:
            if s.hit:
                s.move()
    for s in slides:
        s.draw()
    if slides != []:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (pen.val, freq.val, jmp.val), (1300, 850, 100, 50))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I don't believe it is possible in Pygame alone, I think you'll have to use some other library.

Comment: I tried using Tkinter as well. But still it ignores the Caps-Lock key when the Caps-Lock is closed. Is it a problem about Mac, because the button works normally in other softwares such as Word.

Comment: No. I just don't think they support it. If you do a quick google you can see that a question similar to this was asked, but people said it wasn't possible. You should look into some other libraries to help you do this.

Comment: It is supported - check the answer I just posted. On the other hand althoguht here are libraries hthat might provide a more complete control over knowing the keyboard state, _combining_ another such  library with Pygame might not be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the line bellow in your main loop:

```
capslock = pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CAPS
```

But also, I'd suggest you to take a look into other coding examples on how functions are used, and proceed to some refactoring in this code. Subdividing it into small functions could improve readability a lot in there.